# How to make date picker readonly in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, datepicker

I have  date picker in sencha touch . I want to make it readonly.

Can anybody tell me how to do it. Below is my code :

```
{
            xtype: 'datepickerfield',
            width: '100%',
            labelWidth: '150px',
            labelCls: 'labelFieldCss',
            ui: 'text',
            inputCls: 'selecttext',
            dateFormat: 'M d, Y',
            value: {
                day: new Date().getDate(),
                month: (new Date().getMonth() + 1),
                year: new Date().getFullYear()
            },
            placeHolder: 'Select End Date',
            cls: 'customPlaceholderField',
            id: 'ExpDate',
            label: 'Date'
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Official docs say that you can just use **readOnly: true** property
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.field.DatePicker-cfg-readOnly

Comment: Thanks for reply @Baychurin . But i have already tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: @RajeshKumar- *readOnly* is there for that specific purpose. If you feel that it doesn't work, there must be something else that is incorrect. If you want to just try - **disabled:true**